# How to schedule callbacks in pyglet when subclassing window

Tags: python, pyglet

A typical example of `pyglet.clock.schedule` from the documentation is the following:

```
def callback(dt):
    print(f"{dt} seconds since last callback")

clock.schedule_interval(callback, .5)
```

I have been trying to make this work with a subclassed window. For example:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *


class MyWindow(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        pyglet.clock.schedule(self.test, 0.5)

    def test(self, dt):
        print("test")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = MyWindow(visible=False, resizable=True)
    pyglet.app.run()
```

I get the following error message:

> TypeError: test() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

I would also like to be able to pass additional arguments, like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    pyglet.clock.schedule(self.test, 0.5, val=100)

def test(self, dt, val):
    print(val)
```

but this results in the error message

> TypeError: test() got multiple values for argument 'val'

How can I fix this? I can probably do it by not subclassing the window, but as I understand it, subclassing the window is a common way of organizing pyglet applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to the callback is always the time since last call. You can also pass additional parameters.

First test fix:

```
class MyWindow(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        pyglet.clock.schedule(self.test, 0.5)  # sends dt and 0.5 as args

    def test(self, dt, val):  # val = 0.5
        print("test")
```

Second test fix:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    pyglet.clock.schedule(self.test, 0.5, val=100) # sends dt, 0.5, val=100

def test(self, dt, val0, val): # val0 = 0.5
    print(val)
```

To clarify, the `got multiple values` error means you are providing a parameter as positional as well as named.

Example:

```
def myfunc(p):
    print (p)

myfunc(1, p = 5) # error, sending 'p' parameter twice
```

Also note that the documentation you mention is for `pyglet.clock.schedule_interval` which takes a second argument as time delay. In your code, you are using `pyglet.clock.schedule` which only takes one argument.

Comment: I mistook, as you say, `schedule` for `schedule_interval`. After replacing `schedule` with `schedule_interval`, everything works as expected...